# putting a text and image side by side with aligning the text to the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to put a text and an image side by side, but the text have to be aligned at the bottom but nothing is working, im using twitter-bootstrap and this is the code:

```
<td width="75%" style='padding-top: 50px'  height="100%"  >

     <img src="img/img.png" class="img-responsive " 
         style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 10px;float:right;margin-bottom: 40px"
                width="60%" alt="">
     <span style="vertical-align:bottom;float:right">test</span>

</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zh1o6tuc/

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is what im trying to achieve http://postimg.org/image/ss7u8u6mh/

Comment: Adding `clear: right;` to the `span` will probably do the trick.

Comment: this make the text go below the image.  @Hidden

Comment: Ah, thanks for your edit the question is a bit cleared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a few changes to HTML and CSS:

- Move `span` to before the image in HTML
- Remove `float: right;` from the `span` in CSS
- Add `display: inline-block;` to the `span` in CSS

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 40px
  margin-left: 10px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="75%" style='padding-top: 50px'  height="100%"  >
      <span>test</span>
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="img-responsive "  width="60%" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the float.

Check  http://jsfiddle.net/w4ucrk2p/

Use this next to the image tag,

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

**EDIT :**

If you want the text beside your image, include the span element first inside the `<td>` and then followed by the image. Like,

http://jsfiddle.net/qr18rLd6/

Comment: by next i mean beside the image , this will make the text bellow the image