# prevent line breaks in div

Tags: html, line, break

I have this:

```
<style>
.out {width: 90px; overflow:auto;}
.con {}
.dst {}
img { margin-left: 3px; }
</style><body>
<div class='out'>
<div class='con'>
<div class='dst'>
blablabla bla<img >
</div></div></div>
```

I want the content of the dst div to stay on one line (in the real case out width is 15%). I want it to works in ie6, 7, so no "white-space:nowrap". I know that there are many questions about this but I found no solution. The only solution now is:

```
.con { width: 300px; }
```

But this way the scroll bar is always visible and I want to see it only when needed. Thanks.

**Edited:** Now there is no space before the img, just margin, but still goes on a new line!

Comment: you defined css style for selector `.con`, but you use `class='cont'`

Comment: [This](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#prevent) may help you.

Comment: Wait a minute, 'white-space:nowrap' works on ie6! Why many sites says its supported on 8 or newer ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
.out {width: 90px; overflow:auto;}
.con {}
.dst {}
.dst span{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
img { margin-left: 3px; }
```

```html
<div class='out'>
  <div class='con'>
    <div class='dst'>
        <span>blablabla bla</span>
      <img >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to wrap your text in `<span>` tag to work in **IE6** & **IE7**.

Here is a [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280521/css-white-space-nowrap-does-not-seems-to-work-in-ie)

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn1ndk87/1/)

**PS** : For Text and Image side by side you can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841661/putting-a-text-and-image-side-by-side-with-aligning-the-text-to-the-bottom)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tnx, Bhavin. I cant test this on ie6, 7, can anybody ?

Comment: Wait a minute, 'white-space:nowrap' works on ie6(even on a div)! Why many sites says its supported on 8 or newer ???

Comment: well, i guess that the compatibility problem fixed it self with years, i can accept :)